# Haggadah project: collect links here

Tags: discussion, haggadah-project

Soon we will kick off the content-submission phase of this project, asking people to [prepare questions and answers for publication](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1511/how-should-we-collect-questions-and-answers-for-the-haggadah).  We'll make separate meta posts (for different sections) for the prepared questions; this post is to collect candidate links so that (a) we can get a head start and (b) people who don't have time/ability to prepare something can still nominate content.

I'm making this community wiki.  Please edit the answer below to link to questions you think would be good.  If you can also suggest particular answers and/or the section of the haggadah that it fits in, so much the better.  People preparing questions can harvest this list (delete the link here when you do) or do their own searches; no pressure and no guarantees.

See [this list of tags](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1505/472) for good places to look. **If you don't see the question you want, just [ask it](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)!**

**Submissions (now closed):**

- [Up to Magid](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/haggadah-call-for-submissions-part-1-up-to-magid)
- [Magid](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/haggadah-call-for-submissions-part-2-magid)
- [Rachtzah through Shulchan Orech](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1521/haggadah-call-for-submissions-part-3-rachtzah-through-shulchan-orech)
- [Tzafun through end](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1522/haggadah-call-for-submissions-part-4-tzafun-through-end)

[Final table of contents](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1547/haggadah-table-of-contents)

*I have locked the above-listed posts to that we can import the content into the final document.  Apparently locking removes posts from the main page, which I did not know, but you can get to them all from here.*

You're welcome to use any questions you like.  If you use one from the list in the answer below, edit the answer to take it off the list.

Comment: (When we do the separate sections, I don't think we need 15 sections. Perhaps a Maggid, pre-Maggid, and post-Maggid section should do.)

Comment: Agreed.  Rough sorting is good enough for the amount of content we're likely to assemble in the next two weeks.

Comment: Are you thinking one answer(highest voted, or accepted) per question for the publication? Or are you going to list multiple answers?

Comment: @Jin, I think the general idea is: multiple answers if they're good.

Answer (score 4):

List candidate questions here:

- In Shulchan Orech: the answer https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16010 plus a question that more closely matches it than the one that it was penned as an answer to *([Something similar was done](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1541/759).)*
- In Magid (at the list of plagues): [רַבִּי יְהוּדָה הָיָה נוֹתֵן בָּהֶם סִמָּנִים: דְּצַ"ךְ עַדַ"שׁ בְּאַחַ"ב](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6765)
- At Rochtza (would need much editing down): [Can I wash and say "please pass the salt"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9855/can-i-wash-and-say-please-pass-the-salt) — note that many (most?) people do not salt matza at the seder, so this may not be a good choice
- At Tzafun / Magid (Rabban Gamliel): [Pesach Sheni when Moshiach has just come](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7589/pesach-sheni-when-moshiach-has-just-come)
- At Yachatz, Matzah, or Magid (Rabban Gamliel): [How to explain Matzah Shemurah in 18 minutes](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15527/how-to-explain-matzah-shemurah-in-18-minutes)
- Magid?: [Why did Pharaoh try to kill Moshe?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16929/why-did-pharaoh-try-to-kill-moshe)
- At Rochtza: [Does one need dry hands before washing?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10058/does-one-need-dry-hands-before-washing)
- At Marror / Karpas? (incorporating info from comments): [Marror and Chazeres on the seder plate](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6863/marror-and-chazeres-on-the-seder-plate/)
- At Yachatz: [Lechem Mishlesh?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13933/lechem-mishlesh)

Used:

- In Maggid (at plague of Arov): [What was the Arov?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13458/759)
- In Magid (at "Avadim hayinu"): ["If God had not delivered us from Egypt we would still be slaves"? Really?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9944)
- In Magid (at the four sons): [Why is the wicked son sanctioned for doing what the wise son does?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22332)
- At Hallel: [Are you supposed to do the responsive parts of Hallel at the Seder?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/401/are-you-supposed-to-do-the-responsive-parts-of-hallel-at-the-seder)
- In Magid (at "Dayenu"): [How would Har Sinai without the Torah have been enough?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1457)
- At Matzah or Marror: [Why do we say Pesach seder brachot both nights?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7175/why-do-we-say-pesach-seder-brachot-both-nights)
- In Magid (at the list of plagues): ["Moshe cried out" - really?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/245)
- In Magid  (Dayeinu or "Al hayam laku") [Where did the Egyptians get the wealth they brought to the sea?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13898/where-did-the-egyptians-get-the-wealth-they-brought-to-the-sea)
- These may be too "meta", being pre-seder reading rather than ask-at-the-seder questions, but do we want any of these?  [Beginners' Seder Advice](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15278/beginners-seder-advice), [Advanced Seder Advice](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15277/advanced-seder-advice), [Seder advice when with people who aren't interested?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15285/seder-advice-when-with-people-who-arent-interested)
- Barech (Shefoch chamatecha) or Nirtza: [What do you do with Kos Shel Eliyahu](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6936/what-do-you-do-with-kos-shel-eliyahu)
- In Magid (plagues): [Did hardening Paro's heart mean he wasn't really responsible?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12200/did-hardening-paros-heart-mean-he-wasnt-really-responsible)
- In Magid (at the four sons): [How do we know the rasha would not have been redeemed?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6952)
- At the third or fourth cup: [How can we drink wine after the Afikomen?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15425) (<s>if we can get some citations in the answer</s> citations added)
- Magid (plagues): [Ten plagues of Egypt: hail and pestilence](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8168/ten-plagues-of-egypt-hail-and-pestilence)
- At Nirtza: [Why do we sing "Echad Mi Yodeya"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/857/3)
- At Rochtza: [What is the source of netilat yadayim before eating bread?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8319/what-is-the-source-of-netilat-yadayim-before-eating-bread)
- At Tzafun / Magid (Rabban Gamliel): [Why is there Pesach Sheini - The Second Passover?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1259/pesach-sheini-the-second-passover)
- At Urchatz: [Urchatz - does everyone wash?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6530/urchatz-does-everyone-wash)
- At Nirtza: [How do I get myself to yearn for moshiach if I'm comfortable in the diaspora?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26908/how-do-i-get-myself-to-yearn-for-moshiach-if-im-comfortable-in-the-diaspora)
- At Koreich: [Why do we quote the pasuk from Pesach Sheni for Korech?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26958/why-do-we-quote-the-pasuk-from-pesach-sheni-for-korech)
- At one of the cups: [Nozir and four cups of wine](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8139)
- At Maggid (at list of plague-expansions): [What were the 300 plagues of the Exodus?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7965/what-were-the-300-plagues-of-the-exodus)

Comment: @IsaacMoses Considering we don't dip the matza in salt at the Seder, does it make sense to put in the question about asking to pass the salt?

Comment: @Michoel, the principle applies even if that particular utterance doesn't. If someone edits this for publication, they may consider changing the phrases to something more applicable, like "pass me a kezayit."

Comment: Monica, I think that including one of the "How to Seder" questions at the beginning would be perfectly appropriate. It's on-topic and valuable, since almost anyone who's interested in reading interesting Q&A related to the Seder is also interested in having a good Seder.

Comment: Thanks Isaac.  One question is "which question, or all three?".  (If the latter, we could make an introductory chapter that brings them together.)  People could use our supplement at all sorts of sedarim; are we making assumptions about which ones are most likely, trying to address them all (I think our supplement helps all these cases), or biting off too much by jumping in here?

Comment: Of the three, the one you posted has the richest set of answers. I agree with your point about a wide target audience, so combining the three sounds like a worthwhile exercise.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, I combined them into one post [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1535/472).  I'm thinking that if we use it, it should be either part of the front-matter or an appendix.  These aren't questions you would actually ask during the seder, unlike the rest of our content.  Please add further thoughts there, anybody.