# Haggadah table of contents

Tags: discussion, haggadah-project

An answer to this question will serve as the table of contents published at the start of the 2013 Mi Yodeya haggadah supplement.

I'm populating the table of contents initially but it will be updated as questions are added/removed. Any posts listed in this table of contents must first be an answer to one of these questions (and [formatted like the rest](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1512)):

- [Haggadah call for submissions: part 1 (up to Magid)](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/haggadah-call-for-submissions-part-1-up-to-magid)
- [Haggadah call for submissions: part 2 (Magid)](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/haggadah-call-for-submissions-part-2-magid)
- [Haggadah call for submissions: part 3 (Rochtzah through Shulchan Orech)](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1521/haggadah-call-for-submissions-part-3-rochtzah-through-shulchan-orech)
- [Haggadah call for submissions: part 4 (Tzafun through end)](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1522/haggadah-call-for-submissions-part-4-tzafun-through-end)

You can copy Hebrew section titles from [this](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%92%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%A9%D7%9C_%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97_%28%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%96%D7%99_%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%93%29) online Hagada text.

Answer (score 2):

### Table of Contents

Introduction - [What questions from the Passover Seder do people really want answers to?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1550)

The Seder -

[How can I make an engaging seder?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1535)

[What do the haggadah section titles mean and where do they come from?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1553/472)

קְעָרָה / The Seder Plate — [The beitzah for the seder plate](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1541)

קַדֵּשׁ / Kadesh—

[Why do we link Shabbat with the Exodus from Egypt?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1524)

[Nozir and the four cups of wine](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1557)

וּרְחַץ / Urechatz — [Does everybody wash?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1554/472)

מַגִּיד / Magid —

"עֲבָדִים הָיִינוּ ...‏" / "We were slaves ..." — ["If God had not delivered us from Egypt we would still be slaves"? Really?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1523)

"אַרְבָּעָה בָנִים" / "Four sons" —

[Why is the wicked son sanctioned for doing what the wise son does?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1526)

[How do we know the wicked son would not have been redeemed?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1539)

"יָכוֹל מֵרֹאשׁ חֹדֶשׁ ...‏" / "Perhaps, from Rosh Chodesh ..." — [Why are the commandments for Rosh Chodesh and Passover in the same paragraph?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1549)

"וְגַם אֶת הַגּוֹי אֲשֶׁר יַעֲבֹדוּ דָּן אָנֹכִי ...‏" / "And also the nation that they will serve - I will judge ..." — [Did hardening Paro's heart mean he wasn't really responsible?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1537)

"בְּיָד חֲזָקָה - זוֹ הַדֶּבֶר" / "With an outstretched hand - this is the pestilence" — [What animals were killed by hail, if they were all already dead from pestilence?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1545)

"אֵלּוּ עֶשֶׂר מַכּוֹת ...‏" / "These are ten plagues ..." —

["Moshe cried out" - really?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1533)

[What was the Arov?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1540)

"בְּמִצְרַיִם לָקוּ חֲמִשִּׁים מַכּוֹת ...‏" / "In Egypt, they were struck with 50 plagues ..." — [What were the 300 plagues of the Exodus?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1561)

דַּיֵּנוּ / Dayenu —

[Where did the Egyptians get the wealth they brought to the sea?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1534)

[How would Har Sinai without the Torah have been enough?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1529)

רָחְצָה / Rochtza — [What is the source of netilat yadayim before eating bread?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1551)

מוֹצִיא־מַצָּה / Motzi-Matza — [Why do we say Pesach seder brachot both nights?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1530)

כּוֹרֵךְ / Korech — [Why do we quote the pasuk from Pesach Sheni for Korech?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1556)

צָפוּן / Tzafun — [Why is there Pesach Sheini - The Second Passover?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1552)

בָּרֵךְ / Barech —

[How do we understand "I never saw a tzaddik be abandoned…"?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1558)

[How can we drink wine after the Afikomen?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1538)

[What do you do with Kos Shel Eliyahu?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1536)

הַלֵּל / Hallel — [Are you supposed to do the responsive parts of Hallel at the Seder?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1527)

נִרְצָה / Nirtza —

[How do I get myself to yearn for moshiach if I'm comfortable in the diaspora?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1555/472)

[Why do we sing "Echad Mi Yodeya"?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1546)

[Who made this?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1564/472)

Comment: I put the egg question at the start rather than at the meal, since it doesn't discuss (and its answer barely discusses) eating the egg. I put the hardened-heart question earlier than at the plagues because theplagues have enough questions already IMO. Others should feel free to tweak.

Comment: I chose Shulchan Orech originally because that's a time when there isn't much else to talk about, but plenty of opportunity. Most people IME don't schmooze before Kiddush at the seder about all the prep, but jump into the meat of it.

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree. The question then is whether we want to put things where people can speak about them (I think מוֹצִיא־מַצָּה is out then) or where they are contextually appropriate (and let people speak about them during the meal or at any other time)? Either works IMO, though I like the latter better. **Y'all,** please upvote this comment if you like/prefer the latter (put stuff in context and let people discuss elsewhere) and the comment above it, DoubleAA's, if you like/prefer the former (put stuff where it can be discussed, with context an important but secondary concern).

Comment: Also, perhaps it's worth putting in ShO in order to have at least one per section.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't think we're going to quite make that goal. We are also missing Karpas, Yachatz, and Marror.

Comment: __Jin:__ the questions here are grouped and ordered by section.  Can we somehow convey the section that each question is part of in the formatting?  (Page headers?  Something else?)  "Magid" is a section with sub-sections (as shown above), just for some additional complication. :-)  We've included both Hebrew and English section titles; it'd be good if we could use both.